# whenever i click submit button i get unboundLocalError and local variable 'c' referenced before assignment

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

i have created a form for product table. I included values from multiple table in dropdown box. whenever i finish filling form and clicking submit, it throws me a error of UnboundLocalError. and it also says local variable 'c' referenced before assignment.i didn't understand what mistake i did and I'm new to django environment.

```
model.py
    class Products(models.Model):
        pname=models.CharField(max_length=120)
        pcode=models.CharField(max_length=120)
        category=models.CharField(max_length=120)
        brand=models.CharField(max_length=120)
        supplier=models.CharField(max_length=120)
        description=models.CharField(max_length=120)
        class Meta:
            db_table="products"
forms.py:
    class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
        pname=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
        pcode=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
        category=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
        brand=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
        supplier=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
        description=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
        class Meta:
            model=Products
            fields="__all__"
views.py:
    def addproduct(request):  
        if request.method == "POST":  
                form = ProductForm(request.POST)  
                if form.is_valid():  
                    try:  
                        form.save()  
                        return redirect(show_products)  
                     except Exception as e:
                        raise e
        else:
            form = ProductForm()  
            c=Category.objects.all()
            b=Brand.objects.all()
        return render(request,'addproduct.html',{'form':form,'c':c,'b':b})
 addproduct.html:
      <form method="POST" action="addproduct">  
             {% csrf_token %} 

            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Product Code:</label>
                  {{form.pcode}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Category:</label>
            <select class="form-control" name='category' required='' id='id_category' >
                  {% for cat in c %}
                  <option value='{{cat.id}}'> {{cat.cname}}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
            </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Brand:</label>
            <select class="form-control" name='brand' required='' id='id_brand' >
                 {% for bra in b %}
                 <option value='{{bra.id}}'> {{bra.bname}}</option>
                 {% endfor %}
             </select>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
             <label>Supplier:</label>
                   {{form.supplier}}
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
             <label>Product Name:</label>
                    {{form.supplier}}
             </div>
             <center> <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Submit</button></center>
    </form>
```

Comment: That's because when your request is `POST` and form is not valid, it tries to render your html with categories and brands without actually defined them. Move them out of `else`.

Comment: i moved it out of else also. But now there is no response.Its in same page itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit the form the request is POST and `b`, `c` variable can't assign value. That why the error throws.

Try this

```
def addproduct(request):  
    if request.method == "POST":  
        form = ProductForm(request.POST)  
        if form.is_valid():  
           try:  
              form.save()  
              return redirect('show_products')  
           except Exception as e:
              raise e

    else:
        form = ProductForm()  
    c=Category.objects.all()
    b=Brand.objects.all()
    return render(request,'addproduct.html',{'form':form,'c':c,'b':b})
```

In `urls.py` change this `path('show_products',views.show_products)` to

```
path('show_products',views.show_products, name='show_products')
```

Comment: i tried that but page is not redirecting to show_products. Its in same page and no error came

Comment: If want to redirect then you should declare an url/path then use this in view.py. When you need to redirect, after submit and which page? Give url path for  `show_products`

Comment: I'm redirecting it to a view show_products. In that view i gave the url

Comment: add your `urls.py` in question and where is show product? I can't find anything in your question about show_products

Comment: urls.py                                                                                                                         
              path('show_products',views.show_products),
              path('addproduct',views.addproduct)                                                                                                                                                                  def show_products(request):
    pro=Products.objects.all()
    return render(request,"product.html",{'pro':pro})

Comment: i tried that also but its not working. will there be any other mistakes i have done?

Comment: It shows any error? and does you give valid input in form?

Comment: It doesn't show any error. Everything i gave correctly

Comment: it works but form is not validating and saving the value to the table

Comment: form validation is another issue which is not describe in the question. Input correct value in input field.